# Powershell - Office 365 Mailbox report required to show sent / received emails for multiple mailboxes

Tags: arrays, scripting, office365, ms-office, powershell-2.0

So I am a complete beginner here, just entering the powershell world within 365, using information online I have put this together:

I need to basically export a report of a mailbox from office 365. The report just has to be a simple csv to show sent and received emails like below:

| Email | Sent Emails | Received Emails |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test@domain.com | 400 | 57 |
| newtest@domain.com | 45 | 99 |

```
(Get-MessageTrace -RecipientAddress email@domain.com -StartDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) -EndDate (Get-Date)).count | Export-Csv -Path C:\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
(Get-MessageTrace -SenderAddress email@domain.com -StartDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) -EndDate (Get-Date)).count | Export-Csv -Path C:\file.csv -NoTypeInformation -append
```

The goal here is to grab a count from each query so just a number. I then want these numbers in seperate columns, with a custom title on the columns if possible.

possible to array the mailboxes so that I can edit these on a daily basis based on what mailbox reports we actually need that day?

Am I close with this code? Feel like I would need another 48 hours to get where I want to be xD